# Netbeans remove line counter

Tags: netbeans

It is possible to delete these method's lines counters:
[image]

I was looking in options and I haven't find any way to disable it.

Comment: simple way : expand it :)

Answer (score 0):

To disable line counters go to:

**Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Folding**

At the bottom uncheck *Show summary*.

However there is no option to remove `{...}` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

*Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Folding*

[image]